# tomcat6 jsf2 security manager - IllegalStateException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces, securitymanager

my trouble is

IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

this is my configuration

catalina.policy

```
grant codeBase "http://192.168.0.22:8080/test3/-" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- 
  Servlets
-->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>My first Facelet</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <P>Hello Facelets</P>
        <P><h:outputLabel value="YES, I AM FACELETS"/></P>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

the API download from 
http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html

```
jfs-api.jar
jfs-impl.jar
```

and another library from NetBeans

```
jstl.jar
```

tree aplication

```
test3
 |
 -- index.xhtml
 |
 -- WEB-INF
       |
       -- web.xml
       |
       -- lib
           |
           -- jfs-api.jar
           |
           -- jfs-impl.jar
           |
           -- jstl.jar
```

when i run tomcat

```
$ sh catalina.sh start -security
```

and the error is

```
May 7, 2013 9:00:10 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/test3] appears to have started a thread named [pool-4-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 7, 2013 9:00:10 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/test3] appears to have started a thread named [pool-4-thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 7, 2013 9:00:10 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/test3] appears to have started a thread named [pool-4-thread-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 7, 2013 9:00:13 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.0 (FCS b23) for context '/test3'
May 7, 2013 9:00:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 7, 2013 9:00:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/test3] startup failed due to previous errors
May 7, 2013 9:00:13 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:804)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:306)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:104)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The similar error when i put the listener in the web.xml

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

error:

```
May 7, 2013 9:25:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/test3] appears to have started a thread named [pool-8-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 7, 2013 9:25:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/test3] appears to have started a thread named [pool-8-thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 7, 2013 9:25:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/test3] appears to have started a thread named [pool-8-thread-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 7, 2013 9:25:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
May 7, 2013 9:25:54 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.0 (FCS b23) for context '/test3'
May 7, 2013 9:25:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 7, 2013 9:25:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/test3] startup failed due to previous errors
May 7, 2013 9:25:54 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:804)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:306)
```

what can i do? 
any idea because i don't have it

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once, I increased the heap size of Tomcat JVM, then it worked.
By default minimum memory will be 64m and maximum will be 256m, I'd suggest to increase it from 512m to 1024m.